# SQL: partitioning by column and randomly order results within the partitions

Tags: sql, select, random, amazon-redshift

Suppose I have table

```
DESCRIPTION            SHOP
'tomato pizza'         'Joe'      
'vanilla ice cream'    'Joe'
'oranges'              'Mary'          
'newspapers'           'Mary'
'soap'                 'Bill'
'chips'                'Joe'
...
```

So, each shop (identified by its owner) sells some products and each product appears in the table with a text description.

What I want to do is pulling 10 products from each shop, randomly chosen (for that shop), in one go. 
I know I can use a `ORDER BY random()` but how can I use it in such a way that first a separation by shop (a `GROUP BY`/`PARTITION BY`?) takes place and then randomisation is on the separated results?

Referring particularly to Redshift, which is what I'm using and should be same as PostgreSQL syntax.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `row_number` window function should do the trick:

```
SELECT description, shop
FROM   (SELECT description, shop, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY shop ORDER BY RANDOM()) AS rn
        FROM   mytable) t
WHERE  rn <= 10
```